# How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL but with different and unique index?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a angular app and there is a requirement to pass the different parameters in the url as query params. But we need to pass parameters on id based like : param[1]=23, Here 1 and 23 are dynamic. I have passed the params in the url successfully, like:

```
var myArrayQry = data.map(function(el) {
   return 'params[' + el.id + ']=' + el.quantity;
}).join('&')
```

and our final url is like :

```
http://example.com?params[1]=23&param[7]=26&params[4]=27
```

When we want to get the query params, we used query params like:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res)
})
```

That returns the query params as object, how can I get these params? Because the names are dynamic. Any suggestion?

What I've tried: I have tried `JSON.stringify` and `getAll()` method but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to manually insert the query parameters to the URL. You could leverage the `queryParams` options of the Angular Router.

Note I've also replace the `Array#map` with `Array#reduce` to create an object from the array. Take care there are no overlapping `id`s. If so, the latter value would overwrite the earlier ones.

**Component 1 (*.ts)**

```js
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router) {}

queryParams = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.quantity;
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

this.router.navigate(["/example"], {queryParams: queryParams});
```

Or use it in the template

**Component 1 (*.html)**

```html
<button [routerLink]="['/example']" [queryParams]="queryParams">Click me</button>
```

And get it in component 2.

**Component 2 (*.ts)**

```js
import { ActivatedRouter } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private actRouter: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.actRouter.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
}
```

Comment: I have created this url to redirect  from different site to angular app. I have single page application, where I have created this url on the basis of customer input and redirect to angular app with these params. That why, I have added query params manually.

Comment: @TarnjeetSingh: If you have no knowledge of the query param keys since they're dynamic, how do you intend to use it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I dont have much knowledge of query params, but till now we have used the query params like, check the param if it exist then get its value, but its first time i have a requirement to get value from dynamic params.

Comment: You could do `Object.keys(res)` or `Object.values(res)` inside the subscription to get the keys and values for the object as an array.